# How to enable frag and drop functionality in react native drax

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

**I am trying to implement drag-and-drop functionality in my app using the react-native-drax package, but it is not working. When I click on an item and try to drag it, nothing happens. Can anyone help me with this?**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import {DraxProvider, DraxList} from 'react-native-drax';

const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');

const getItemStyleTweaks = alphaItem => {
  return {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    height: 50,
  };
};

const AppTest = () => {
  const [alphaData, setAlphaData] = React.useState(alphabet);
  return (
    <DraxProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DraxList
          data={alphaData}
          renderItemContent={({item}) => (
            <View style={[styles.alphaItem, getItemStyleTweaks(item)]}>
              <Text style={styles.alphaText}>{item}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          onItemReorder={({fromIndex, toIndex}) => {
            const newData = alphaData.slice();
            newData.splice(toIndex, 0, newData.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
          }}
          keyExtractor={item => item}
          horizontal={true}
          flatListStyle={{
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </DraxProvider>
  );
};
```